# What is the sql server permission requirement for user account used in the DEA (Database Experimentation Assistant) tool?

Tags: sql-server, database-experimentation-assistant

I am planning to capture trace using the DEA (Database Experimentation Assistant) tool.

What is the sql server permission requirement for user account used in the DEA tool?

Answer (score 2):

From [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), required permission is as below:

> Replaying a trace requires that the user running DEA:
>
> Can connect to the target database server using Windows
> authentication. Has sysadmin rights on the target database server. In
> addition, replaying a trace requires that:
>
> The service account running the target database servers has write
> access to the trace folder path. The service account running
> Distributed Replay clients can connect to the target database server
> using Windows authentication. TCP ports are opened for incoming
> requests on the Distributed Replay controller. DEA communicates with
> the Distributed Replay controller by using COM interfaces.

Analysis configuration requirements

> Performing the analysis requires that the user running DEA:
>
> Can connect to the analysis database server using Windows
> authentication. Has sysadmin rights on the source database server.

There is a great video on this topic from Dustin Dorsey, you may go through that for more details:

https://sqlbits.com/sessions/event20/Baselining_Performance_with_DEA

Comment: Can you point me to some links about how to enable `Distributed Replay controller` - I have question separately for this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311143/how-to-turn-on-the-distributed-replay-dreplay-in-sql-server