# How to turn on the Distributed Replay (DReplay) in SQL Server for DEA (Database experimentation assistant)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, database-experimentation-assistant

I want to turn on the Distributed Replay (DReplay) in SQL Server. Where can I find this setting?

Comment: Also note that Database Experimentation Assistant doesn't _have_ to use DReplay.  It includes a copy of OStress which doesn't require any setup.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - please can you elaborate on why DReplay would not be required? I ask because the documentation has DReplay mentioned in it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It's the "InBuilt" replay tool mentioned here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-replay-trace?view=sql-server-ver15  Much of the docs focus on DReplay because it's complex, and the option of using the "InBuilt" replay agent was added later.  And honestly OStress has always been better than DReplay for most scenarios.  OStress comes from the RML Utilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/replay-markup-language-utility

Answer (score 3):

There are few very good article on Distributed Replay - one by [David Klee](https://www.heraflux.com/resources/howto/sql-server-distributed-replay/):

> Distributed Replay requires two services that are available in the SQL
> Server installation procedure: the Distributed Replay Controller and
> the Distributed Replay Client.  Although a Controller can manage up to
> sixteen Clients (Enterprise edition), only one of each may be
> installed on a single server.
>
> For this proof-of-concept, we will use a single replay machine with
> one Controller and one Client for simplicity. This configuration is
> not generally recommended in a live environment for performance
> reasons.
>
> Prior to starting the installation of the services, it is advisable to
> pre-create the directories required for the installation.  The Client
> will require a working directory and a result directory. By default,
> these are placed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\DReplayClient.  Neither are usually automatically created by
> the installer.

Other one from Vitor Montalvão:

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-configure-and-use-sql-server-distributed-replay/

You may refer this one as well:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3084/configure-sql-server-distributed-replay-feature/

Things to note here - this is installed as service and hence it could be set as manual or automatic service similar to SQL Server or Agent service.

Also to note that it is installed as a separate service.

Comment: The 1st link says *The Microsoft SQL Server Distributed Replay feature has been provided by Microsoft since SQL Server 2012 and it is used to replay captured traces against an upgraded test environment.* - does it need installing on source or target server or both please?

Comment: You have to install it at least one place. Read the linked documents. It outlines what's needed. You can install it one place, and have it target somewhere else. It's just a connection string. However, it has to run somewhere. You can have it run in multiple places, in order to get threaded execution. Again, read the linked articles.